# Is there a clean way of starting a task execution straight away with asyncio.create_task()?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following code:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def coro_1(seconds=5):
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)

async def main_1():
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(coro_1())
    # Long computation here
    time.sleep(5)
    await task_1

async def main_2():
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(coro_1())
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    # Long computation here
    time.sleep(5)
    await task_1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    asyncio.run(main_1())
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Main_1 took { end - start } seconds.')
    start = time.time()
    asyncio.run(main_2())
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Main_2 took { end - start } seconds.')
```

The output:

```
Main_1 took 10.005882263183594 seconds.
Main_2 took 5.005404233932495 seconds.
```

I understand that `main_1` coro takes longer as the `time.sleep()` does not happen "concurrently" with the `asyncio.sleep()`. As far as I understand, this is because the task does not start its execution until the main_1 coro "yields" the execution in the `await task_1` sentence.

In `main_2` this does not happen because we allowed the start of the task by "yielding" with `await asyncio.sleep(0)`.

Is there a better way of achieving this behaviour? I would like to create a task and have it started straight away without needing an explicit `asyncio.sleep(0)` so my code runs faster. I feel like adding sleeps all over the place is ugly and adds a lot of boilerplate code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can *fake* it being a task:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def coro_1(seconds=5):
    print("c1 start")
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
    print("c1 end")
async def coro_2():
    print("c2 start")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("c2 end")

async def main_1():
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(coro_1())
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(coro_2())
    await asyncio.gather(task_1,task_2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    asyncio.run(main_1())
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Main_1 took { end - start } seconds.')
```

But it's a hack and it's fragile, I'm not sure if anyone guarantees that the tasks get called in their order of creation. Also, the asynchronous one only *starts*, so it runs up to its first `await`, and then the synchronous one runs completely. This is more visible with a multi-step example:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def coro_1(label):
    print(f"{label} start")
    for c in range(1,6):
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
      print(f'{label} {c}')
    print(f"{label} end")
async def coro_2(label):
    print(f"{label} start")
    for c in range(1,6):
      time.sleep(1)
      print(f'{label} {c}')
    print(f"{label} end")

async def main_1():
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(coro_1("async1"))
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(coro_1("async2"))
    task_3 = asyncio.create_task(coro_2("heavy"))
    await asyncio.gather(task_1,task_2,task_3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    asyncio.run(main_1())
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Main_1 took { end - start } seconds.')
```

This one produces the output

> ```
> async1 start
> async2 start
> heavy start
> heavy 1            <--
> heavy 2            <--
> heavy 3            <-- no yield, completely synchronous
> heavy 4            <--
> heavy 5            <--
> heavy end
> async1 1
> async2 1
> async1 2
> async2 2
> async1 3
> async2 3
> async1 4
> async2 4
> async1 5
> async1 end
> async2 5
> async2 end
> Main_1 took 9.072734117507935 seconds.
> ```

Where you can very well see how the `await`s yield, which then result in the first `asyncio.sleep(1)`s waiting (not running) in parallel with each other and with the synchronous "task". The synchronous task never yields, runs completely, then the remaining 4-4 seconds are waited together. That's what these `async-await` things generally do (in other languages too), they *wait together*, but they still run on a single CPU core by default, actually doing one thing at a time.

Then if you're content with using a single CPU core - so have exactly 1 CPU-intensive computation, you can use `to_thread`. The heavy function is not `async` any more, and I replaced `time.sleep()` with an actual busy loop to show they really overlap:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def coro_1(label):
    print(f"{label} start")
    for c in range(1,6):
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
      print(f'{label} {c}')
    print(f"{label} end")
def ro_2(label):
    print(f"{label} start")
    for c in range(1,6):
      next = time.time() + 1
      while time.time() < next:
        pass
      print(f'{label} {c}')
    print(f"{label} end")

async def main_1():
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(coro_1("async1"))
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(coro_1("async2"))
    task_3 = asyncio.to_thread(ro_2,"heavy")
    await asyncio.gather(task_1,task_2,task_3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    asyncio.run(main_1())
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Main_1 took { end - start } seconds.')
```

Produces this output:

> ```
> async1 start
> async2 start
> heavy start
> heavy 1
> async1 1
> async2 1
> heavy 2
> async1 2
> async2 2
> heavy 3
> async1 3
> async2 3
> heavy 4
> async1 4
> async2 4
> heavy 5
> heavy end
> async1 5
> async1 end
> async2 5
> async2 end
> Main_1 took 5.1116883754730225 seconds.
> ```

And then another answer arrived already, so I just stop here.

Answer (score 2):

doing the `long computation` in the main thread is wrong, as you will be stalling the eventloop, which is the main reason why you think you need the `asyncio.sleep(0)`, your async functions shouldn't be doing any notable computations such that you require them to yield prematurely.

instead you should submit the computation to be done asynchronously in another thread/process.

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def coro_1(seconds=5):
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)

def long_computation():
    # Long computation here
    time.sleep(5)

async def main_1():
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(coro_1())
    task_2 = asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, long_computation,)
    await asyncio.gather(task_1, task_2)

async def main_2():
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(coro_1())
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    task_2 = asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, long_computation,)
    await asyncio.gather(task_1, task_2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    asyncio.run(main_1())
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Main_1 took { end - start } seconds.')
    start = time.time()
    asyncio.run(main_2())
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Main_2 took { end - start } seconds.')
```

```
Main_1 took 5.004462718963623 seconds.
Main_2 took 5.004127025604248 seconds.
```

now `await asyncio.sleep(0)` is not needed.